# Stored procedure to trim table

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to trim 2 columns user NVARCHAR2(32) and record NVARCHAR(80) in a table LT_NAME.
Initially these columns were CHAR so I need to trim them. razorsql crashes as the table has 40,00,000 records. Could someone suggest a stored procedure in Oracle to do this ?

Comment: Please give us some more

Answer (score 1):

With that amount of data it might take some time for an `update` statement to complete. Moreover, it'll generate a large amount of undo and redo data. if you need to update an entire table, not its portion, the CTAS would be, because of direct-path read(SGA will be bypassed) and little redo generating, the fastest way to get it done, but you will spent some time on rebuilding table-related schema objects, constraints, and granting privileges. So a typical scenario would be:

- Create a new table using CTAS.
- Rebuild all indexes on new table, if there were any indexes on old one
- Recreate constraints if there were ones, triggers.
- Drop old table
- Rename new table
- Grant appropriate privileges

Setup:

```
/* This small utility package is needed to simply display the size of redo  */
SQL> create or replace package PKG as
  2    g_redo number := 0;
  3    procedure initialize;
  4    procedure show_redo;
  5  end;
  6  /
Package created 

 SQL> create or replace package body pkg as
  2    procedure initialize is
  3    begin
  4      select ms.value
  5        into pkg.g_redo
  6        from v$statname sn
  7        join v$mystat   ms
  8          on (ms.statistic# = sn.statistic#)
  9       where sn.name = 'redo size';
 10    end;
 11  
 12    procedure show_redo is
 13      l_redo number;
 14    begin
 15      select ( ms.value - pkg.g_redo ) / 1024
 16        into l_redo
 17        from v$statname sn
 18        join v$mystat   ms
 19          on (ms.statistic# = sn.statistic#)
 20       where sn.name = 'redo size';
 21       dbms_output.put_line('redo size: ' || to_char(l_redo) || ' KB');
 22    end;
 23  end;
 24  /
Package body created
```

Test table `t1` contains, in this example, only 1 200 001 rows.

```
SQL> select count(*) as cnt
  2    from t1;


cnt
----------
   1200001
```

Here is how much time and redo it takes to `update` 1 200 001 rows:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> set timing on;
SQL> set autotrace off;
SQL> set feedback off; 

SQL> exec pkg.initialize;

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> update t1 
  2     set col1 = trim(col1)
  3       , col2 = trim(col2);

Elapsed: 00:00:28.67

SQL> exec pkg.show_redo;

redo size: 421024.28515625 KB 

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Here is how much time and redo СTAS takes:

```
SQL> exec pkg.initialize;

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> create table t2(col1, col2) as 
  2    select trim(col1) 
  3         , trim(col2) 
  4      from t1;

Elapsed: 00:00:01.85

SQL> exec pkg.show_redo;

redo size: 163 KB
```

Of course your time and redo size will be different, but CTAS will take much less time and redo than a regular `update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Applying an UPDATE to forty million records is going to take a long time, no matter how you do it.

The actual query is straightforward enough:

```
update your_table
set user = rtrim(user) 
    , record = rtrim(record)
/
```

That ought to run in SQL*Plus, provided your DBA has provisioned the UNDO tablespace sufficiently for a database with tables of such size.

You ought to lock the entire table before you begin, or start the database in restricted mode if that's an option.  This is to ensure you can update the entire table in one fell swoop.

---

If you feel this doesn't answer your question, please edit it to provide more details, giving the constraints you're operating under and perhaps explaining why RazorSQL crashed.